# Custom "placeholder" on UITextField being truncated unexpectedly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, placeholder

I'm trying to create a text field with a persistent "placeholder" of sorts by adding a UILabel as a subview of the text field. However, my label keeps being truncated, and I can't figure out why. Any advice is much appreciated!

Here's what I'm currently getting (it's supposed to say "first name": 
[image: Current]

Here's the code I have:

```
#import "LabeledTextField.h"

@interface PlaceholderLabel : UILabel
@end

@implementation PlaceholderLabel

-(void)drawTextInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    UIEdgeInsets insets = {0, 10, 0, 0};

    return [super drawTextInRect:UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(rect, insets)];
}

@end

@interface LabeledTextField ()

@property (nonatomic) PlaceholderLabel *placeholderLabel;

@end

@implementation LabeledTextField

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self)
    {
        _placeholderLabel = [[PlaceholderLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, [self frame].size.height/2, 0, 0)];
        [_placeholderLabel setBackgroundColor:UIColorFromRGB(0xdedede)];
        [_placeholderLabel setTextColor:UIColorFromRGB(0x787878)];
        [_placeholderLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:kTextFieldPlaceholderFontSize]];
        [_placeholderLabel setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail];
        [_placeholderLabel setNumberOfLines:1];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    [self setLeftView:_placeholderLabel];
}

-(void)drawPlaceholderInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    return;
}

-(void)setPlaceholder:(NSString *)placeholder
{
    [_placeholderLabel setText:placeholder];
    [_placeholderLabel sizeToFit];
}

-(CGRect)leftViewRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds
{
    CGRect frame = [_placeholderLabel frame];
    frame.origin.y = (self.frame.size.height - frame.size.height)/2;
    frame.size = [[_placeholderLabel text] sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:kTextFieldPlaceholderFontSize]];
    return frame;
}
@end
```

Comment: Did you try to override the method `leftViewRectForBounds:` and return the rectangle needed to show the label?

Comment: See my edit: tried that, getting the same result.